# How to search for a constant value by posting the column name in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have created this code to retrieve multiple user data where the pincode = the pin-code i am posting through post method and $value = 't'($value = a column name(i want to send the column name using post method(column name= a, b, ho, ll, c, d)) where i want it to look for 't'). my code is not complete and i don't know how to do it can anyone help me with this? Later i want it to connect with android app and list view the retrieved data.

My function in DbOperations.php

```
<?php

class DbOperations{

    private $con;

    function __construct(){

        require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';

        $db = new DbConnect();

        $this->con = $db->connect();

    }
public function gettestuser($pin){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM test_category WHERE $value = 't' pin = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$pin);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    }
```

My gettestuser.php

```
<?php
require_once '../include/DbOperations.php';

$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
if(isset($_POST['reg_pin'])){

    $db = new DbOperations();

    $test_category = $db->gettestuser($_POST['reg_pin']);

    var_dump($test_category);

        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['pid'] = $test_category['pid'];
        $response['name'] = $test_category['name'];
        $response['pin'] = $test_category['pin'];
        $response['a'] = $test_category['a'];
        $response['b'] = $test_category['b'];
        $response['ho'] = $test_category['ho'];
        $response['ll'] = $test_category['ll'];
        $response['c'] = $test_category['c'];
        $response['d'] = $test_category['d'];



}else{
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
}
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Can I just check that I understand your question? Are you trying to read a value posted to the page?

Comment: @MikeyBunny I am just trying to look for a constant value('t') in the specific column and that column name i am trying to post through editText box... I have tried it using Postman check this [screen shot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/351gx9ifl8coyg1/gettest.PNG?dl=0) to find out what i actually want to do.

Comment: First of all you need to pass that `$value` into function (from `$_POST`). Second, before you execute the query ensure it matches one of whitelisted strings or it will be used to inject part of the query.

Comment: @shudder please explain editing my script...

Comment: @shudder your reply??

Comment: @Sumit, he is saying that you are not passing the column name into your `gettestuser` function. Also you should make sure that the posted column name is a valid column name from your table before trying to execute the query, otherwise a hacker will post a weird value for the column name that will allow them to access things from your database that you don't want them to access. Read up about SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Wodin i guess that's the only thing i am asking in this question... how to pass column name using post method to look for a constant $value = 't'. i want to know the code for this.?

Comment: @SumitPal You do it in the same way that you are doing it for `reg_pin`. Assuming your form field is called `col_name`, you would do something like this: `function gettestuser($value, $pin){...}` and `$db->gettestuser($_POST['col_name'], $_POST['reg_pin'])`

Comment: @Wodin can you please answer it editing my code..?

Comment: @SumitPal I have done so. Please check my answer.

Comment: Such a db structure makes no sense and MUST be changed. As a side effect, it will solve the current problem as well

Comment: @YourCommonSense can you please explain it a little more?

Comment: @shudder please check my updated DbOperations.php

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

DbOperations.php:

```
public function gettestuser($col_name, $pin) {
    $valid_columns = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 1, 'ho' => 1, 'll' => 1, 'c' => 1, 'd' => 1);
    if (!array_key_exists($col_name, $valid_columns)) {
        throw new Exception('Bad column name');
    }

    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM test_category WHERE $col_name = 't' pin = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $pin);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
}
```

gettestuser.php:

```
<?php
require_once '../include/DbOperations.php';

$response = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['reg_pin']) && isset($_POST['reg_value'])) {
        $db = new DbOperations();

        $test_category = $db->gettestuser($_POST['reg_value'], $_POST['reg_pin']);

        var_dump($test_category);

        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['pid'] = $test_category['pid'];
        $response['name'] = $test_category['name'];
        $response['pin'] = $test_category['pin'];
        $response['a'] = $test_category['a'];
        $response['b'] = $test_category['b'];
        $response['ho'] = $test_category['ho'];
        $response['ll'] = $test_category['ll'];
        $response['c'] = $test_category['c'];
        $response['d'] = $test_category['d'];
    } else {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Wodin! let me check it once, if it works i'll mark it as an answer... or else i'll let you know in comment if i get any problem.

Comment: Still getting an error "Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\wamp64\www\Android\include\DbOperations.php on line 47" and my line 47 is $stmt->bind_param("s", $pin);

Comment: OK, that is a separate issue. I think it would be best to ask another question about that and provide more of `DbOperations.php` so that it's possible to tell what `$this->con` is.

Comment: it's a connection... class DbOperations{

  private $con;

  function __construct(){

   require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';

   $db = new DbConnect();

   $this->con = $db->connect();
  
  }

Comment: @SumitPal I was just adding to the code you wrote the changes to accomplish the stuff you were asking about. You did not say that the `bind_param()` call was not working before. That is a separate issue.

Comment: I've already said that " my code is not complete and i don't know how to do it can anyone help me with this?"... anyways, the thing is, can you help me further?